Grafana variable filter is not displaying all variable values
I am using Grafana 10 and influxdb v2.7.4.
I am using below flux code to create grafana variable for my dashboard.
When i test this on influxdb script editor, i can get 3500 Client_Name variable values.
But when i apply this as a variable and open the variable filter on dashboard the values are truncated. In alphabetic order i can only get until variable names starting with f… Nearly %70 of the variable value Client Names are missing in the filter. How can i display all 3500 Client Name variable filter values in the dropdown filter?
import "influxdata/influxdb/schema"
schema.tagValues(
bucket: "VFBckStrg",
tag: "Client_Name"
)

The strange thing is.
If i create variable from influx 1.8 with influxql, i can see 3500 client names at variable creation page by preview of values section at bottom of page.
If i create variable from influx v2.7.4, i can only see 1000 client names at variable creation page by preview of values section at bottom of page.
Note : Influxdb 1.8 db and influxdb 2.7.4 db has same data. We are planning to pass to 2.7.4 version. But couldnt do it because of this limitation yet.

Sounds like a limitation (or maybe bug?) in data source plugin. Consider filing and issue in grafana's repo.

Thanks markalex. the strange thing is this is only happening in flux language in influxdb v2.7.4. Not happening in influxdb 1.8 with influxql.

I'd argue flux and influxql being different languages, and possibly having two different stacks involved both on Grafana's side and Influx's - it's not surprising at all to find difference of behaviour or bug.

Influxql is old language. Flux is new language. But because of this limitation we cannot stop using influxdb1.8 and we cannot pass to influxdb 2.7.4.

Grafana has 1000 items limit for variables.
See https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/59959
